# Deleted LUKS Disk

Tags: linux, grub, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I had a dual-boot laptop setup with an encrypted BIOS. I then removed my Manjaro installation and deleted all of the partitions, including the Manjaro partition, which included my LUKS disk. When I now boot my laptop, I get the following error message:

```
error: no such cryptodisk found, perhaps a needed disk or cryptodosk module is not found.
error: disk 'cryptouuid/...' not found
Entering rescue mode...
```

I tried booting from a USB stick, but the rescue mode only allows me access `(proc)` and says that the file system is unknown if I try to boot from anything. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Except for the LUKS header, an encrypted filesystem is essentially indistinguishable from random data if the encryption is any good and you don't have the key/passphrase.

Before you write anything else to the disk, you should use `testdisk` (available on many live Linux media) and see if it can restore the partition table. If you haven't made any other changes after deleting the partitions, this could be easy.

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Once the partition table is recovered, you can use `cryptsetup open /dev/sdX sdX_crypt --type luks`  (where `sdX` is your encrypted partition) to unlock the encryption.

If successful, you can then mount it with e.g. `mount /dev/mapper/sdX_crypt /mnt` to access it.